# XSS vulnerabilities: how dangerous are they?

Tags: xss

A lot of articles underline that [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerabilities can be very dangerous for the website on which they exist. I wonder how much is this true when we find these XSS vulnerabilities on the frontend of a website, in fields such as the search forms?

Comment: Read about the Apache foundation XSS story. You will be amazed :)

Answer (score 3):

Cross-site scripting vulnerabilities are extremely dangerous, because they allow the attacker to control the victim's browser to some extend.

This can be used for all kinds of malicious actions:

- stealing sensitive cookies or reading personal pages (the user account, private messages etc.)
- making requests on the victim's behalf (e. g., ordering products via the victim's account and sending them to an arbitrary address)
- exploting the trust of the victim in the site; for example, an attacker might render a fake login form and prompt the user to enter the password. Or they might trick the user into downloading a malicious file which looks like it's served by the site.
- attacking the server through a privileged account

So while XSS may look less dangerous than, say, SQL injections at first site, it's actually a major threat for both your users and your server.

Comment: Don’t forget IE’s capability to execute arbitrary ActiveX controls on trusted sites which can result in execution of arbitrary commands on the victim’s machine.

Comment: @Gumbo Can you explain that a bit more? I didn't know that yet and have not read of it.

Comment: @Xatenev `new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").run("calc")`

Comment: @Gumbo Oh haha, that works? n1 to know, thnaks

Comment: @Xatenev This works only on sites which are configured as [trusted sites](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-zones-adding-removing-websites).

Comment: @Gumbo one other question, is it possible to write XSS code in URL for chrome browsers? cause chrome blocks a lot of XSS right away.

Comment: @Xatenev There are ways to [bypass Chrome’s XSS filter](https://www.google.com/search?q=bypass+chrome+xss+filter).

Comment: XSS detection is limited to reflective attacks, anyway. If the malicious code is stored in the application (persistent XSS), then it's almost impossible to distinguish from a legitimate script. A much more effective tool is the `Content-Security-Policy` header. This can be used to turn off all scripts except those coming from a trusted domain.

Comment: @Fleche Yea, when you inject XSS code per SQL Injection like document tag a href="www.givemeyoursession.com" its quite sad for the website admin.